# Browser screencasting

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

Hey, I'm trying to make a web app that allows users to write on a virtual drawing pad and record their drawings as the progress as a video. I know there's screen casting software out there, in fact, I have such software on my computer but I'm trying to create this ability online. Would anyone be able to suggest where I should start looking so that I could figure out how to do this?

I have pretty good programming skills with in flash and I'm good with php.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Elaborate, what software do you have, programming knowledge etc ect?

Comment: That sounds like it is probably pretty tough. Flash might be one way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into internet whiteboard software, like [this one](http://cristian.nexcess.net/ajax/whiteboard/).  A company called GroupBoard offers this as a service, including free offerings.  Their stuff isn't great, but they're one of the only companies who offer it without requiring use of a browser plugin.

The link I provided contains tutorials for creating a whiteboard using AJAX alone.

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to write the functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [this product](http://www.groupworld.net) which allows you to record a collaborative whiteboard session, and optionally have it automatically uploaded to Vimeo. It can be embedded on your website.